# jpeg picture saved with Camera.takePicture require long time to be shown

Tags: android, camera, jpeg

Why does the pictures taken by the camera using takePicture(null, null, picture) require long time to be shown? Even if I set the parameters to save the image at low resolution (e.g., 640x480) and the image file is less than 80 KB, opening it require long time (e.g., > 10 sec). It does not happen with other images captured by the android camera even if they are at high resolution.

Comment: You created the image file yourself? If you later copy this file elsewhere, will the copy open faster?

Comment: Yes Alex. It is strange. I've moved the image in another folder and now they open very quickly! So, summarizing, when the images are in the folder /mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Memories/ they open very slow. When I move the same images to /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/ they open quickly! Can you explain me why and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really... I don't know what's wrong with `/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Memories/`. If I were you, I would've tried to begin with writing to `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/` - see if you immediately have a *fast* image, or you still need to copy. Next, try some other location.